# Angular2 seed: lang_1.global.System.import is not a function

Tags: angular

I lazy load my component:

{ path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: 'app/+dashboard/dashboard.module' },

When I run the dev build its works fine. When I run the prod build of Angular2 seed I get the following error:
lang_1.global.System.import is not a function ;

It goes wrong in this part of the code:

```
    var _this = this
      , _a = path.split(_SEPARATOR)
      , module = _a[0]
      , exportName = _a[1];
    return void 0 === exportName && (exportName = "default"),
    lang_1.global.System["import"](module).then(function(module) {
        return module[exportName]
```

path = app/manager/+dashboard/dashboard.ma.page.module
_SEPARATOR = #

I also posted it on angular2 seed GitHub: https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed/issues/1253 Anyone expierence the same issue?

*edit*

I found my answer
Lazy loading modules is not yet supported